# Pandas Multiple Conditional Mean With Group By

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

New to python and pandas. I have a pandas DataFrame with list of customer data which includes customer name, Reporting month and performance. I'm trying to get first recorded performance for each customer

```
  CustomerName ReportingMonth  Performance
0         7CGC     2019-12-01     1.175000
1         7CGC     2020-01-01     1.125000
2          ACC     2019-11-01     1.216802
3         ACBH     2019-05-01     0.916667
4         ACBH     2019-06-01     0.893333
5          AKC     2019-10-01     4.163636
6          AKC     2019-11-01     3.915215
```

**Desired output**

```
      CustomerName  ReportingMonth   Performance
0             7CGC      2019-12-01      1.175000
1              ACC      2019-11-01      1.216802
2             ACBH      2019-05-01      0.916667
3              AKC      2019-10-01      4.163636
```

Comment: Could you please share what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) or [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df.sort_values('ReportingMonth').groupby('CustomerName', as_index=False).first()
```

or

```
new_df = df.sort_values('ReportingMonth').drop_duplicates('CustomerName',
                                                          keep = 'first')
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
  CustomerName ReportingMonth  Performance
3         ACBH     2019-05-01     0.916667
5          AKC     2019-10-01     4.163636
2          ACC     2019-11-01     1.216802
0         7CGC     2019-12-01     1.175000
```

If it is already sorted you don't need sort again

Comment: one quick follow up, how can i change this to show customer name, reporting month and performance? current method only shows the performance. other than that it is perfect!!

Comment: doesn't `df.sort_values('ReportingMonth').drop_duplicates('CustomerName', keep = 'first')` show all?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the dataframe that i got with this code